Is the first version of Ken Thompson's DBM library still available?
Per Wikipedia,

In computing, a DBM is a library and file format providing fast, single-keyed access to data.

...

The original dbm library and file format was a simple database engine, originally written by Ken Thompson and released by AT&T in 1979.

Unfortunately, references in the Wikipedia article do not include a pointer to the 1979 Ken Thompson's source code. Can it be found somewhere?

gdbm seems to be derived from dbm. and at least comes with a compatible interface Maybe it's worth looking there.

@tofro I'm interested in the original assumptions and limitations. In gdbm they would be long gone.

The Unix Heritage Society archives of V7 (AT&T, 1979) and 32V (AT&T, 1979) both include source code for libdbm, so you can probably use that until you find something better.
If the dates are to be believed, the 32V source code is older than the V7 source code.  Curiously, there is but one comment in the 32V source code:
int hitab[16]
/* ken's
{
    055,043,036,054,063,014,004,005,
    010,064,077,000,035,027,025,071,
};
*/
 = {    61, 57, 53, 49, 45, 41, 37, 33,
    29, 25, 21, 17, 13,  9,  5,  1,
};


which suggests someone else was also involved.

I forgot about TUHS, and on Bitsavers, the tape image is of an unknown format. file X7252.2015_UNIX_V7.tap says data. strings on it finds "61, 57", but does not find "ken's" - it is likely the same V7 version.
